# On windows, connect to a Virtual PV VM running Ubuntu for things like memcached, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtualbox

I am on Windows 7, building an ASP.net web application.

There are a few services that I need to connect to, and don't want to go through the hassle of installing them on Windows.

I also run VirtualBox with Ubuntu.

Can I install memcached (for example) on Ubuntu, and then connect to it from my windows operating system? If so, how?

**Update**

There seems to be a confusion in what I'm asking.  I just want to connect to services running on my Ubuntu virtual machine from my host/parent windows 7 operating system.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have installed Memcached (or in fact any other software) on the guest, you can easily connect to that instance from the host (Windows 7 in your scenario). You have to configure the VirtualBox to let the guest and the host to talk to each other.

There are **[different networking modes in VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)** (Bridged Networking, Internal Networking, Host-Only Networking etc).  Based upon your requirement you can configure the appropriate networking mode by following the instructions in the URL.

I have Ubuntu 11.04 as Guest and Host OS using VirtualBox and I have installed Hadoop on them. I configured VirtualBox for Bridged Networking and the applications in the host and the guest were able to talk to each other. The disadvantage of the Bridged Networking is that the Host has to be connected to a physical network (through a router or something, so that the host and the guest can talk to each other). If the host machine is not connected to a physical network then Host-Only Networking should be configured in the VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Actually sounds like this might be better asked as multiple questions (1)How can I install memcached on Ubuntu and (2) How can I connect my asp.net app to a memcached instance running on a separate Ubuntu machine.

You may want to check out this article where the author basically tries to do exactly what you're doing:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/Memcached.aspx

Pretty sure you can install memcached on ubuntu via apt these days:

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
/etc/init.d/memcached restart
```

Comment: Hi, my quesiton is how to connect to a virtualpc from the host computer, not how to install memcached (that was just an example).  From my host computer (windows 7), I want to connect to the e.g. memcached running on the VM.

Comment: you want to use something like Memcached Manager to manage the memcache instance from Windows - http://allegiance.chi-town.com/MemCacheDManager.aspx

Comment: I don't think you get what I'm asking :)  I don't want to install memcached on windows, let's forget memcached for a moment.  I want to connect to services running on my ubuntu VM from my windows (host/parent operating system).  Get it?

Answer (score 1):

Most of these services already listen for commands over TCP/IP ports. All that is left is to setup the required networking. There are many configuration possible, ranging from the guest being able to only talk to the host, and up to the guest being fully equal to the host as a network computer.

A good place to start is this tutorial :
[Network & sharing in VirtualBox - Full tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-network-sharing.html),
which explains nicely all the concepts and software, and with many screen-captures.

Comment: On my windows host computer, I want to connect to services running on the Ubuntu VM, so for example, my web application that I am developing on the windows computer can connect to services on the VM like memcached, redis, mysql etc.   So yes, I would need the VM to have an IP address and then a seperate port for each service (which they all usually run on a specific port anyhow).

Comment: This is certainly feasible, and in fact I do this frequently. If the VM is configured correctly, then it is just another computer on the network. Does your question pertain to VirtualBox network setup ?

Comment: yes the network setup is what I don't get.

Comment: I have edited my answer.